# Server 2012 R2 DC resolves DNS for domain PC's but not for itself

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Having a problem with a Server 2012 R2 standalone DC.

It is able to resolve DNS for the domain PC’s, but it can’t resolve DNS for the server itself.

BPA reports 2 errors:

AD DS: The domain controller FBSERVER.. must be able to reach a DNS server and retrieve DNS records that are associated with this domain controller

DNS: Zone _msdcs.. is an Active Directory integrated DNS Zone and must be available.

DCDiag /test:DNS /v   reports:

```
   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\FBSERVER
      Starting test: Connectivity
         * Active Directory LDAP Services Check
         The host
         ed7fe2ed-4fe2-4d5b-9f31-2ab3af7ceaa4._msdcs.<mydomain>.<mysite.org>
         could not be resolved to an IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP,
         server name, etc.
         Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your
         firewall settings.
         ......................... FBSERVER failed test Connectivity
```

Below are the troubleshooting steps I’ve taken so far.

Nothing I do seems to work.

Please help.

Thanks.

---

- Disabled the firewall (Symantec Endpoint Protection)
- nltest /dsregdns
- ipconfig /flushdns && ipconfig /registerdns
- net stop netlogon && net start netlogon
- Backup, delete, and restore the zone:

  C:\Windows\System32>dnscmd /ZoneExport . zonebackup
  DNS Server . exported zone
    . to file C:\Windows\system32\dns\zonebackup
  Command completed successfully.

  C:\Windows\System32>dnscmd /ZoneDelete . /dsdel /f
  DNS Server . deleted zone .:
      Status = 0 (0x00000000)
  Command completed successfully.

  C:\Windows\System32>dnscmd /ZoneAdd . /Primary     /file zonebackup /load
  DNS Server . created zone .:
  Command completed successfully.

  C:\Windows\System32>dnscmd /ZoneResetType .     /dsprimary
  DNS Server . reset type of zone .:
  Command completed successfully.

Comment: What's the output of `IPconfig /all`?