# DNS server cannot resolve addresses itself

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a very similar issue to the one here: [Server 2012 R2 DC resolves DNS for domain PC's but not for itself](https://serverfault.com/questions/875548/server-2012-r2-dc-resolves-dns-for-domain-pcs-but-not-for-itself)

We also have a Server 2012 R2 standalone DC abd are getting very similar issues (not exactly the same BPA errors though). The Server cannot resolve names itself but is serving DNS fine for all other clients on the network. I'm scratching my head a bit on this. It used to work fine so I'm not sure what has changed. Has anyone else experienced this. Is it just a coincidence that the other poster an I have the same error on the same OS/set-up or has a recent windows updated caused the issue?

---

Here's an update - the dcdiag seems to have highlighted some issues but I'm unsure exactly how to resolve them.

There is only one domain and this server is the DC and DNS server for it. Other clients work fine. The server is 2012 RC.

I’ve checked DNS is running and added a dependency with netlogon as one article suggested. DNS forwarders are in place for the server (no conditional ones), there are two both pointing to our ISPs servers. 
The server reports no internet connection but will happily ping something like 8.8.8.8 with a quick response.

A ping to something like www.google.com will get “Ping request could not find host www.google.com. Please check the name and try again.”

A ping against an internal machine name (e.g. a desktop (“sageclient”) on the network) will eventually reply with an IPV6 address. Forcing the ping to IPV4 will also eventually work (both are slow operations to respond though).

There is a single name server in each DNS zone which is the DNS server itself.

The bindings on the network card have IPV4 before IPV6.

Nslookup fails with a timeout like this:

Server:  dnsservername.local
Address:  192.168.1.10
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to dnsservername.local timed-out

Using DCDIAG
dcdiag /test:DNS

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = 
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: \
      Starting test: Connectivity
         The host 8ffb49d7-8284-49b2-ad87-da2593bbb868._msdcs..local
         could not be resolved to an IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP,
         server name, etc.
         Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your
         firewall settings.
         .........................  failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

Testing server: \

```
  Starting test: DNS

     DNS Tests are running and not hung. Please wait a few minutes...
     ......................... <dnaservername> passed test DNS
```

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

Running partition tests on : Schema

Running partition tests on : Configuration

Running partition tests on :

Running enterprise tests on : .local
      Starting test: DNS
         Test results for domain controllers:

```
        DC: <dnaservername>.<domain>.local
        Domain: <domain>.local


           TEST: Basic (Basc)
              Error: No LDAP connectivity
              No host records (A or AAAA) were found for this DC

           TEST: Dynamic update (Dyn)
              Warning: Failed to delete the test record dcdiag-test-record in zone <domain>.local

        TEST: Records registration (RReg)
           Error: Record registrations cannot be found for all the network
           adapters

     Summary of DNS test results:

                                        Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
        _________________________________________________________________
        Domain: <domain>.local
           <dnaservername>                  PASS FAIL PASS PASS WARN FAIL n/a

     ......................... <domain>.local failed test DNS
```

As requested, here's the ipconfig /all output

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : <hostname>
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : <domain>.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : <domain>.local

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 98-4B-E1-10-47-25
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd7d:286d:f42::48(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::219f:a22f:7e25:f762%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::ace5:eaff:fe5b:b672%12
                                       192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 261639137
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-B7-B0-12-98-4B-E1-10-47-25

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5873D6A3-377F-4EEF-9059-1AEF3F5D20C6}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Jeebus. How can we answer this? You haven't given us any details about your configuration or any details about the problem. Linking to another question that is very similar doesn't help. It may be similar but it isn't the same. How about giving us some details and tell us what you've tried so far to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Hi - sorry about that, I've added some more details and just run a dcdiag which might help point to he issues.

Comment: What are your DNS Servers. please add `ipconfig /all` output

Comment: In the TCP/IP setting in the NIC on the DC, what is the DC using for DNS?

Comment: Hi - sorry, I was off yesterday. in the NIC on the DC, the DC is using itself for DNS (primary). There is no secondary set-up.

Comment: I've added the ipconfig /all output to the post

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this. For some reason (due to an update?) the server only wanted to respond to DNS requests from itself on IPV6 by default. The NIC on the server had no IPV6 primary DNS configured. As soon as I set that to the server itself, everything started working again.